# Bundled product js error on 1.9

Tags: prototype-js

I have the following error when clicking on bundled tab in product back office :

```
prototype.js:612 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at path/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:69
at path/js/prototype/prototype.js:865:29
at path/js/prototype/prototype.js:825:18
at Array.forEach (native)
at Array.each (path/js/prototype/prototype.js:824:12)
at Array.collect (path/js/prototype/prototype.js:864:10)
at String.evalScripts (path/js/prototype/prototype.js:612:34)
at Function.<anonymous> (path/js/prototype/prototype.js:391:23)
at path/js/prototype/prototype.js:416:23
```

More precisely Chrome underline this part : *script) });*

```
function evalScripts() {
    return this.extractScripts().map(function(script) { return eval(script) });
  }
```

But I can't get what's goes wrong.

And I have also the following one when clicking on add an option

```
(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: bOption is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
onclick @   (index):1
```

Which I suppose come from the previous error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same result, and it was caused by a single quote on a translation.

My website was in French, and this translation was causing the issue in **app/locale/fr_FR/Mage_Catalog.csv**

"Delete Option","Supprimer l'option"

Else, try to **console.log** the script variable, it may give you clues.

Hope this help!

Comment: Mine is in french to. I will try as soon as possible. TY

Comment: Look like it work now. Merci beaucoup.